Flink : Would like to create Pipeline in seqential in Flink
Team ,
I am working on Flink. Here is my requirement

Read the Events from Kafka
Apply Transfromation on the events
Sink to MongoDB
Produce Atomic Events to Kafka

Here, i am facing problem in implementing step 3, 4 in sequence.
1, 2 are connected by streams and DataStream will be output of Step2 , at present i am sending output of step 2 to step 3 , Step 4.
But i would like to implement step 3 then step 4.

I can return the output of Step 3 to Step 4, But Step 3 is just sinkToMongoDB i am not returning any from step 3.

I would like to build everything as pipeline and continuous stream.

That's not possible. Flink requires that sinks be terminal nodes in the job graph.
When all of the sinks support two-phase commits, you don't have to worry about the dual write problem, and everything will just work. But I'm not sure what guarantees the MongoDB sink provides. An alternative might be to write a separate job that reads from Kafka and writes to MongoDB (I realize that's not the ordering you asked for, it just seems more practical).

I agree on Flink requires that sinks be terminal nodes in the job graph.
Just exploring processFunction for MongDBSink and use out.collect(value); under processElement. Once it got emitted another stream can get and process to kafka.
Since i need transformed data to be sent to mongoDB and after send to kafka to ensure data is persisted in mongo.

Doing synchronous I/o from a processFunction is an anti-pattern that can cause checkpoint failures. So be careful.
